# Редактирование кода для массива

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

[image: Не могу исправить ошибки.помогите кто то с кодом,позязязя:3]
Не могу исправить ошибки.помогите кто то с кодом,позязязя:3

Comment: Если хотите помощи, уберите картинку и приложите код. А пока -1

Comment: #include "stdafx.h" 
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
 const int size = 10;
 double arr[size], arr2[size];
    int j = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  arr[i] = ((abs(sin(pow(i + 1, 2))) - 3.5)* (sin((i + 1) - 1) - 3.44));
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  cout << "arr[" << i << "]=" << arr[i] << endl;
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (arr[i]>0) {
   j++;
   const int size2 = j;
   double arr2[size2];
   arr2[j] = arr[i];
   cout << "arr2[" << i << "]=" << arr2[size2] << endl;
  }

 }

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и вставьте код туда

Comment: но я же не могу тогда ошибок показать.а так скрин с ошибками

Comment: Что мешает указать текст ошибки?

Comment: Текст ошибки можно взять из лога сборки, который печатается а окошке `Output` (и сохраняется как файл в папке сборки).

Comment: кажется перебор с ханжеством *картинка-код*, понятно же всё и вполне наглядно, зачем эти излишества? ответ можно в комментарий уместить, вместо этого развели тут пионерское собрание и отбиваете человеку желание обращаться с вопросами

Comment: @Anatol здесь не лавочка добрых людей, а база данных знаний для последующего использования. Предложите алгоритм индексирования картинок поисковиками и у меня не будет никаких вопросов

Comment: @AntonShchyrov так-то я придерживаюсь аналогичного мнения, тут лавочка злых людей. Но тем не менее, что на этой картинке индексировать? Другой вопрос, что заголовок нужно исправить и тд, но картинка тут абсолютно не лишняя

Comment: @Anatol например, текст ошибки

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я ж говорю, текст ошибки в заголовок можно добавить, например, но что такого в этой картинке, что её прям принципиально надо выпилить или закрыть вопрос? Это перебор, скрин прекрасно иллюстрирует проблему и дополняет вопрос.

Comment: @Anatol Вот лениво мне рассматривать картинку с кодом на телефоне

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что нельзя объявлять массив с размером `size2`, во время компиляции неизвестным. Кстати, даже если бы получилось - то вы тут же вышли бы за границы: `arr2[j] =`... От того, что вы присвоили `size2` значение `j`, которое меняется на каждой итерации - суть дела не меняется: компилятор понимает, *для чего* вы ее используете, и сообщает об ошибке...