# Нужно из положительных элементов одного массива создать другой массив

Tags: c++

Дано массив А,из положительных элементов которого нужно создать другой массив В.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 


int main() 
{ 
    const int size = 10; 
    double arr[size]; 
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
        arr[i] = ((abs(sin(pow(i + 1, 2))) - 3.5)* (sin((i + 1) - 1) - 3.44)); 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
        cout << "arr[" << i << "]=" << arr[i] << endl; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i]>0){
            j++;
            const int size2 = j;
            double arr2[j];
            arr2[j]= arr[i];
            cout << "arr2[" << i << "]=" << arr2[j] << endl;
        }

    } 

system("pause"); 
return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять, что не так?

Comment: Есть код, но визуал студио выбивает ошибки, хотя в дев с++ всё работает. Не пойму, что не так --

Comment: У меня ошибки, но я их вам не покажу, потому что у вас документов нет, ага.

Comment: Прикол не понял!

Comment: Я тоже что-то не понял, вы предлагаете гадать что у вас за ошибки или как?

Comment: Понял, исправлюсь.

Comment: Меня удивляет то, что когда просишь помощи у людей, которые, казалось бы, могут помочь и тебя тупо минусуют, вместо того чтоб дать ответ.

Comment: То, что вы отправляете второй раз один и тот же код под другим именем - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741576/Редактирование-кода-для-массива/741598 - вряд ли можно считать корректным поведением... И, как видите, ответ тот же... Не верится? :)

Comment: Вы не поверите, но это не я. Я не знал что такой вопрос уже есть.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в этой строке

```
double arr2[j];
```

дело в том, что devc++ использует mingw (то есть, gcc), который поддерживает [vla](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), а студия - нет. Нужно заменить на `std::vector<double> arr2(size);` Но это уберет жалобу компилятора, но не ошибку в коде.

А ошибка в том, что пишем за пределы массива. Более того, массив постоянно пересоздается. Это явно не то, что нужно. Массив нужно создать перед циклом.

Код не пишу - так как не ведомо как именно Вам можно "писать".

Comment: Прикол в том, что задача не моя. Меня попросили помочь. И у меня ноут не тянет Визуал Студио, я писал код на Дев С++. Там всё работает.